# 3d coordinate graphing

Tags: 3d, wolfram-mathematica, graphing, coordinate

how do I plot 3d coordinates in mathematica? I am trying to plot 3d points using mathematica.  I want to view what they look like after I am done too.  so far this is what I have done... I have thousands of points to plot fyi.

input

```
a = {{2, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 9}, {6, 4, 5}, {5, 7, 5} , {7, 2, 1}} 
ListPointPlot3D[a]
```

output

```
{{2, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 9}, {6, 4, 5}, {5, 7, 5}, {7, 2, 1}}
ListPointPlot3D[{{2, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 9}, {6, 4, 5}, {5, 7, 5}, {7, 2, 1}}]
```

I see no graph.
thanks in advance for the help!
-JOE

Comment: I see four points when I do that ListPointPlot3D.

Comment: Using Mathematica 7, I also see four points in a 3D box.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If `ListPointPlot3D` returns unevaluated, and you have not changed anything that would prevent it from working, perhaps you are using Mathematica 5 and copied this code from somewhere else.

In that case, try using:

```
a = {{2, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 9}, {6, 4, 5}, {5, 7, 5}, {7, 2, 1}};

Show[Graphics3D[Point /@ a]]
```